# Interactive output directory r

Tags: r

Is there a function/package in R that allows us to choose where the output folders are going to be stored? I wrote a script which reads several xlsx files and then store them into folders in my computer. But I will use this script in several computers, so I cannot use

`path <- "C:/Users/Dev/Desktop/test/"`

since it will change every time. I tried

`path <- choose.dir(default = "", "Choose the output path")`

but i don't get any output.

This is the code:

```html
setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))

library(xlsx)
library(tcltk)

#get file names
f = list.files("./")

#read files
dat <- lapply(tk_choose.files(caption="Choose your files"), function(i) {
  x <- read.xlsx(i, sheetIndex = 1, sheetName = NULL, startRow = 24,
                 endRow = NULL, as.data.frame = TRUE, header = FALSE, Filters = Filters[c("xlsx")])
  #return columns with names and colors
  x <- x[, c(2, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19), drop = FALSE]
  #return the data
  x
})

library(plyr)
df1 <- ldply(dat, data.frame) ## convert list into a dataframe

#remove NA's
complete.cases(df1)
x <- df1[complete.cases(df1),]
str(x)

#show specific rows
df1$X2 <- gsub("[[:punct:]]","-",df1$X2)
df <-df1[grepl("^[0-9]|^[a-zA-Z][0-9].*", df1$X2), ]

#output path
pth <- choose.dir(default = "", "Choose the output path")

# Iteratate within each row of df
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if (!file.exists(pth))
    # Create 1st path
    dir.create(paste0(pth , df$X2[i]), na.omit(df$X2[i]))
  # Create 2nd and 3rd paths
  dir.create(paste0(pth, df$X2[i], "/",df$X5[i]), na.omit(df$X2[i]))
  dir.create(paste0(pth, df$X2[i], "/",df$X7[i]), na.omit(df$X2[i]))
  dir.create(paste0(pth, df$X2[i], "/",df$X9[i]), na.omit(df$X2[i]))
  dir.create(paste0(pth,  df$X2[i], "/",df$X11[i]), na.omit(df$X2[i]))
  dir.create(paste0(pth,  df$X2[i], "/",df$X13[i]), na.omit(df$X2[i]))
  dir.create(paste0(pth,  df$X2[i], "/",df$X15[i]), na.omit(df$X2[i]))
  dir.create(paste0(pth,  df$X2[i], "/",df$X17[i]), na.omit(df$X2[i]))
  dir.create(paste0(pth,  df$X2[i], "/",df$X19[i]), na.omit(df$X2[i]))
}
```

Comment: You can use a relative path (relative to the current working directory) though that's not interactive

Comment: I don't want a relative path, because the output folders will be stored at totally different directories in every device.

Comment: Oh okay, I see what you mean